# Do I unlock 3 magic items or 2 from the "Ritual of Divination" DM Quest in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

Do I unlock 2 items or 3 from the DM Quest for the Ritual of Divination?

The DM Quest for the Ritual of Divination requires that I join both AL Facebook groups and I follow them on Twitter. I don't currently do so, and so I am asking if joining both Facebook groups equals a different membership. So do I unlock two or three magic items?

Answer (score 2):

The 8.01/.02 version of DM Quests is not as clear as the 8.00. In 8.01 it is broken up into three columns (using bullets for clarity):

> - **Ritual of Divination**
> - Join both AL Facebook groups and follow us on Twitter
> - Unlock 1 item from Magic Item Table F for each membership you have

So the "both Facebook" and singular "Twitter" add up to three.

Per 8.00, there was what you had to do:

> **Ritual of Divination**. Join both the general AL and AL DM group on Facebook, and follow us on Twitter.

But it then has a separate listing with what you earn:

> **Ritual of Divination**: For each membership that you have (max 3), you may
>   unlock one item on magic item table F for one of your
>   characters.

In 8.01, they combined them into one listing, but neglected to add the "(max 3)" part.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what the (now) v8.02 wording says for the reward (i.e. how it's changed): "Unlock 1 item from Magic Item Table F for each membership you have."